# Decorator written with class,Pycharm to say "Unexpected argument ",is the pycharm bug?

Tags: python, pycharm

[image]

```py
class Delay:
    def __init__(self, sec):
        self.sec = sec

    def __call__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        return self.wrapper

    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        import time
        time.sleep(self.sec)
        result = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        return result

@Delay(2)
def myfunc(n):
    return n * 2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(myfunc(6))
```

Comment: PyCharm evidently can't infer how your decorator changes the function signature (or doesn't, in this case).

Answer (score 2):

`wrapper()` needs to be a closure inside `__call__` and don't forget to add a  `@wraps()` decorator to preserve function metadata:

```
from functools import wraps


class Delay:
    def __init__(self, sec):
        self.sec = sec

    def __call__(self, func):

        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            import time
            time.sleep(self.sec)
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return result

        return wrapper


@Delay(2)
def myfunc(n):
    return n * 2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(myfunc(6))
```

[image]